# stub all methods called on a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mocking, double

In one of my tests I need to completely disable all calls to a given class, so I did the following:

```
  ApiClass = double("api_class").as_null_object
```

It works fine, however I receive following warnings now:

```
~/my_project/spec/models/mymodel_spec.rb:141:warning: already initialized constant ApiClass
~/my_project/app/models/api_class.rb:2:warning: previous definition of ApiClass was here
```

what is the alternative which wouldn't cause those warnings?

ps. i just realized that what i did is totally wrong, because it actually replaces class with a stub in global context for all tests unless i restore the class after performing my test.

Comment: What about this? https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-0/docs/verifying-doubles/using-a-class-double

Comment: hm, got "undefined method `class_double'" with this one..

Comment: `class_double` was only added to rspec in 3.0.0.beta1 (moved from rspec-fire)

Comment: right, my version is 2.14.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `stub_const`, described in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-11/docs/stubbing-constants to avoid these warnings, as follows:

```
stub_const("ApiClass", double("api_class").as_null_object)
```